# How to stop key from being dispatched

Tags: java, swing, listener, keyboard-events

Is it possible to stop a key from being dispatched? I basically want to disable the number pad from firing its numbers - it should fire a macro instead. The problem is it does both. Here is the code:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent keyEvent) {

    //If key has macro assigned then fire that (working fine) 

    if (keyEvent.getKeyLocation() == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD) {
         return true;
    }
}
```

Reading the spec for KeyEventDispatacher, if returning false it says it will pass the event on. It appears to be doing the same for true. Is there a way of stopping it from passing the event on? Or am i doing something stupid?

Thanks,

Comment: Use KeyBindings instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call [`consume()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#consume%28%29) on the event to show it has been handled.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent keyEvent) {

    if (keyEvent.getKeyLocation() == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD) {
         keyEvent.consume();
         return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the dispatchKeyEvent receives 3 events. Doing what you said works for 2 of the events - KeyPressed and KeyReleased as it knows where the key came from. However, there is a 3rd one called KeyTyped and this seems to lose all knowledge that it came from the keypad. Any idea why that is? This is some of its ToString:             java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_TYPED,keyCode=0,keyText=Unknown keyCode: 0x0,keyChar='4',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN